# implementation details of std::bind: binder's usage of std::placeholder

Tags: c++, std

How placeholders substituted with actual calling arguments during a call internally in binder's call operator? How order of the arguments to be substituted is calculated?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    void foo( std::string first, std::nullptr_t second, int third);
    auto binder = std::bind( foo, std::string("first"), 
                                  std::placeholders::_2, 
                                  std::placeholders::_1 );
    binder( 42, nullptr );
}
```

Placeholders are used to substitute unbounded paramater in functor resulting from call to std::bind, not in original callable passed to std::bind. Following code will result in error.

```
auto binder = std::bind( foo, std::string("first"), 
                              std::placeholders::_3,   // instead of _2
                              std::placeholders::_2 ); // instead of _1
```

I'm curious how to implement binder's call operator in order to be able to tie placeholders to original callable's arguments order so code above will compile and run ok. Also why following code is working correctly?

```
int sum( int lhs, int rhs )
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}
auto f_sum = std::bind( sum, 3, std::placeholders::_2 );
auto s = f_sum( 5, 7 ); // returns 10
```

Please provide as simple as possible code and motivation behind it.

Comment: Did you look at the implementations in libc++ (clang) or stdlibc++ (gcc)?  They're both on github.

Comment: @StephenNewell no, I looked to MSVC code and struggled to embrace it.
Also I forgot to ask to provide as simple as possible code and motivation behind it.

Comment: The idea is easy. The implementation is hard. Capture the bind parameters into a tuple. When invoked, capture the actual parameters as another tuple. Build a third tuple by copying the bind parameters, except that if you see a placeholder, copy the corresponding actual parameter. Call with the tuple, and then coerce the return value as necessary.

Comment: Your second `binder` needs three arguments to be called. Like `f_sum`, the first argument is ignored